# Regex to extract id and value

Tags: java, regex

I have a html input element from which I need to extract the name and value using two separate regex (Java).

```
<INPUT type="hidden" id="Region" value="Circuits Japan" checked="false">
```

I need to extract Region and Circuits Japan from above using 2 different regex.

For id extraction, I used something like this `.*id=(.[^"]+`) and it gives me

```
Region value=Circuits Japan checked=false>
```

whereas I'm trying to extract only "Region". 
Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Cheers:-)

Comment: In your regex you are looking for the end quote, but in your example you don't have quotes. Which is correct?

Comment: Your example has a broken HTML, you can't really parse that trough a RegEx for all possible HTML strings. However if it is `<INPUT type="hidden" id="Region" value="Circuits Japan" checked="false">` then of course you can.

Comment: without quotes you can't possibly parse `Circuits Japan` as a single value. How do you know that `Japan` is part of the value attribute and not the name of the next attribute?

Comment: What am I saying! it is with quotes. Apologies fellas.

Comment: `id=(".*?")` works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: parsing attributes of html using a single regex is hard to do, because order of attributes can vary.
If you want to do multiple passes it's not that hard.
Given that you don't have `"` then the regex for id would be:

`id=(\\S+)`

Of course you can't parse multiple word attributes like that. You will need `"` just to properly represent such attributes. Assuming you have multiword attribute with `"` around then you should use:

`someAttribute=\\"([^"]+)`

Answer (score 2):

If the input element is under your control, you should use quotes for your attribute values, i.e:

```
<INPUT type="hidden" id="Region" value="Cirvuits Japan" checked="false">
```

then use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( " id=\"(.*?)\" value=\"(.*?)\"" );
Matcher m = m.matcher( inputString );
if ( m.find() ) {
    String id = m.group(1);
    String value = m.group(2);
    ...
}
```

If you cannot control the quotes just use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( " id=(.*?) value=(.*?) checked=" )
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise specified, the `+` operator is greedy...that means it will match as much as it possibly can.  In your case, that means it's going all the way to the last `"`.  to make the `+` match without being greedy, add a following `?`.  E.g.:

```
.*id=(.[^"]+?)
```

Then you should get the value you're expecting.

Answer (score -1):

have you considered [Apacke Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), [here](http://blog.jeroenreijn.com/2010/04/metadata-extraction-with-apache-tika.html) is a blog which shows how to use it.

Comment: Thanks - But this is a totally different context.

Answer (score -1):

Here is javascript approach on extracting the id of elements

```js
let htmlElement = '<div id="123"><div id="new"></div></div>'
const extractIdInstanceFromElement = (htmlElement)=>{
  let htmlElementIds = htmlElement.match(/id=\"(.*?)\"/g);
  return htmlElementIds.map(item=> {
    let checkItem = item.split('id=')[1].split("");
    const [, ...last] = checkItem;
    last.pop()
    return last.join('') })
}
console.log(extractIdInstanceFromElement(htmlElement))
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.