# How to return id from string JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var str = '<input style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTR2VDVmOQ8AKjqY1bMHgCGYXhFchnAg6omJGcBXEZRtNoXYK2dMsaMt1qtD9/3p40x5yS9tHI6o1wuz1lrVzpWXLDWTg3pz/0CQnd2Jos49xUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center; cursor: auto; outline: 1px solid blue;" autocomplete="email" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control mat-input-server ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" matinput="" name="email" required="" id="mat-input-112621" placeholder="E-mail Address" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" value="" type="email">'
```

how do i return **id="mat-input-112621"** from this string, all that html code will be a string so just trying to return the id.

Comment: Does the string come from a trusted source or no?

Comment: Is there just the one id? Can you just use a regex?

Comment: Any specific rules this string follows? Is the id always in the same place, then do `var id = str.substring(591, 608);`. Otherwise you may use a regex, or a simple search. It all depends on what the rest of the string may be. This question doesn't contain enough detail to answer it properly.

Comment: @GolezTrol: then why not just `var id = 'mat-input-112621'`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Then it is not read from the string at all.

Comment: @GolezTrol: So?  We got the answer desired.  Perhaps my tone didn't come through; I was attempting to be ironic.  Your suggestion (especially before its edit) captured no contextual information at all.  And if you're going to ignore the context of an obvious string of HTML, then why not ignore the string itself?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, me too. That was roughly the point I wanted to make. Providing an answer that could be serious, but was likely too simple, so OP would say "Doesn't work because.... " and then hopefully would consider next time to put those reasons in the question upfront. :-) Sorry about the misconception, I will go to bed now.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Sorry I missed the joke.  Especially when I proceeded to make the same one.  I guess we both need sarcasm indicators.  :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract an ID value from a string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403831/extract-an-id-value-from-a-string-with-javascript) and of [Regex to extract id and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177315/regex-to-extract-id-and-value)

Answer (score 2):

You could create an element, insert the string into it and then ask for the first child's `id`

*Note, if the string will hold more than one HTML element, which as well has an `id`, you will need to adjust this solution accordingly.*

```js
var str = '<input style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTR2VDVmOQ8AKjqY1bMHgCGYXhFchnAg6omJGcBXEZRtNoXYK2dMsaMt1qtD9/3p40x5yS9tHI6o1wuz1lrVzpWXLDWTg3pz/0CQnd2Jos49xUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center; cursor: auto; outline: 1px solid blue;" autocomplete="email" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control mat-input-server ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" matinput="" name="email" required="" id="mat-input-112621" placeholder="E-mail Address" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" value="" type="email">'

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;
console.log(el.children[0].id);
```

Comment: Suggest using `el.children[0].attributes.id` as it actually returns `id="mat-input-112621"`, also this is easily to read for future modifications (different props)

Comment: Assuming the string will always contain one element, or at least the desired element as a first element. Op specified nothing, and this answer is just a guess.

Comment: @GolezTrol How can this be a guess, the OP presented a string which this solves.  If they add that it can be more than one element in the given string, then an adjustment will be needed, but not before.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Anything's a guess when it's only based upon examples.  But given the usual contexts of JS, the guesses here seem quite reasonable.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Have you tested what result `el.children[0].attributes.id` will be? ... if you do you'll see that will not just return the id

Comment: @LGSon _how do i return id="mat-input-112621" from this string_ seems OP doesn't need actual value of id

Comment: There can always be some weird edge cases that are not covered, but this question is completely without specifications. I fail to see why two high rep users take stabs at the answer instead of closing the question or at least asking for clarification. This Q&A will hardly be useful for OP and not at all for anyone else.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly OP ends their question with _"...so just trying to return the id"_

Comment: @GolezTrol You didn't answer if you downvoted? ... I showed a perfectly valid and great way how to extract an id from a string holding an html element, though I agree it were a short one, so how is that useless for anyone else (OP included)?

Comment: @GolezTrol agreed, sometimes there are bunch of up votes for super simple answer for stupid question, but this might not be the case tho

Comment: Moral of story - _don't hurry, as tomorrow OP can change the question, and your answer with bunch of upvotes won't be valid anymore_, anyway you got my +1 for equilibrium

Comment: So you're still on a net 38 points. Mission accomplished. And you're right, it's a perfectly valid way to extract the id of a single element. Too bad nobody is going to find it, because the question doesn't say anywhere that isn't about a single element.

Comment: @GolezTrol Stopped counting points after 25k....just wanted to know if a high rep. user downvote a good answer when it were the question they actually had issues with.

Comment: If I think a question is bad, I downvote the question. If I think an answer is bad, I downvote the answer. I'm not punishing answerers for poor questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex.

If it's guaranteed to be there, then this might do:

```js
var str = '<input style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTR2VDVmOQ8AKjqY1bMHgCGYXhFchnAg6omJGcBXEZRtNoXYK2dMsaMt1qtD9/3p40x5yS9tHI6o1wuz1lrVzpWXLDWTg3pz/0CQnd2Jos49xUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center; cursor: auto; outline: 1px solid blue;" autocomplete="email" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control mat-input-server ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" matinput="" name="email" required="" id="mat-input-112621" placeholder="E-mail Address" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" value="" type="email">';

console.log(str.match(/\b\id="([^"]+)"/)[1])
```

If not, you might have to check whether the match exists before taking its first group.

Comment: Regexing html terrible idea tho

Comment: Oh, of course, as a general parsing technique.  (And yes, I know the classic SO post about that; it's one of my favorites.)  But for specific tasks, it can work fine.  My guess, although I'm not sure, is that the syntax for a single element is a regular language.